# Explanation of sed pattern

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Can someone explain the following sed pattern (OSX):

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\'$'\n/g' -i filename
```

I know that it places every character of a string in a newline. 
However, I do not understand how the substitution works with the pattern `\(.\)` and `\1\'$'\n`.

Comment: Hi, the \\( and \\) are necessary for the regex grouping - means group every character. So then the replacement for the group is used with \1. There is a replacement for bash when using \'$'. The simple sed regex would look like s/\\(.\\)/\1\$\n/g

Comment: That sed command is almost same as doing  `fold -w1 filename`

Comment: This isn't quite right; the version of `sed` that comes with macOS requires an extension for the backup file after `-i`, or an explicit empty string (e.g. `sed ... -i '' filename`) to not make a backup. BTW, the expression itself can be simplified to `sed -e $'s/./&\\\n/g' ...` or equivalently `sed -e 's/./&\'$'\n/g'`

Answer (score 0):

To `'s/\(.\)/\1\'$'\n/g'`
Fast way:

Substitute `s`, by the term `(.)` and substitute by the same term `\1` with end of line '$'\n`, globally`g`

Part by part:

`s`: Substitute

First `/`: Delimiter for beginning the term to watch
`\(.\)`: Find anything with a with of size 1 - Here, the parenthesis create a reference and, the parenthesis are isolated with `\` to indicate to not be part of search term.

Second `/`: Delimiter to end of the term and begin the substitution term
`\1`: Get the first reference as delimited by `\(.\)` in the term to watch. If needed, we can do more references

`'$'`: The end of line with bash escapes, so, the interpretation on sed is `$`

`\n`: new line

`/`: End of the substitution term

`g`: Do globally or, continue to search even if you already found the search term in the line

Comment: This isn't quite right; the `'$'` in the middle ends the single-quoted section, then starts a section in ANSI-C-escaped section (so that `\n` will get translated into an actual newline). The backslash just before that then escapes (to `sed`) the resulting newline. The two levels of quote/escape interpretation (first bash, then `sed`) makes this really confusing.